# getting class cast exception while running simple hadoop program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a simple hadoop program from eclipse and I am getting the below exception .Please help to resolve the issue**

```
2019-09-02 21:32:13,528 WARN  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:createSortingCollector(417)) - Unable to initialize MapOutputCollector org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
java.lang.ClassCastException: interface javax.xml.soap.Text
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:903)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:1018)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:782)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported `javax.xml.soap.Text` when you mean to import `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`.